# Is creating objects in html and having functions considered bad practice in oop?

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I'm just learning about JS and oop and was wondering whether creating objects in HTML and calling fuctions there is considered a bad practice. For example in the onclick event like in the example bellow. Also is it allowed to have functions which are not methods? Like having one function where I'd be creating all the objects and calling their methods.

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
<input id="second_name" type="text" placeholder="Second Name">
<button onclick="const name = new Person('first_name', 'second_name', 'output'); name.writeName()">Show name</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

```
class Person {
       constructor(first_name_id, second_name_id, output_id) {
           this.first_name = document.getElementById(first_name_id)
           this.second_name = document.getElementById(second_name_id)
           this.output = document.getElementById(output_id)
       }
       writeName() {
           return this.output.innerHTML = "Your name is" + this.first_name.value + " " + this.second_name.value
       }
   }
```

Comment: On-events are discouraged (ex. `<a onclick=...`) but using JavaScript in most other forms isn't (`eval` and `with` being rare exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using old-style `onxyz`-attribute event handlers is that you can only use *global* functions in them. The global namespace on browsers is **very** crowded, and so it's best to avoid adding more to it when you can avoid it.

In your example, you might consider ensuring that the button can be identified with a CSS selector (or an `id`) and then hooking up your handler using modern techniques like `addEventListener`:

```
const theButton = document.querySelector("selector-for-the-button"); // or = document.getElementById("the-button-id");
theButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const name = new Person('first_name', 'second_name', 'output');
    name.writeName();
});
```

That way, `Person` doesn't have to be global.

This is particularly useful when combined with *modules* (whether JavaScript's native modules or those provided by Webpack, Rollup, and similar).

Here's a complete example, notice that it doesn't use any globals:

```js
{ // Scoping block to avoid creating globals
    class Person {
        constructor(first_name_id, second_name_id, output_id) {
            this.first_name = document.getElementById(first_name_id);
            this.second_name = document.getElementById(second_name_id);
            this.output = document.getElementById(output_id);
       }
       writeName() {
           return this.output.innerHTML = "Your name is " + this.first_name.value + " " + this.second_name.value;
       }
    }
    
    document.getElementById("show-name").addEventListener("click", function() {
        const name = new Person('first_name', 'second_name', 'output');
        name.writeName();
    });
}
```

```html
<input id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
<input id="second_name" type="text" placeholder="Second Name">
<button id="show-name">Show name</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, yes, that is a **very bad** practice. To make something clickable(like a button), use this code in a **separate** JS file.

```
// Anoymonous function
varName.addEventListener("click", function(){
alert("hi")
})
```